# BPMS or just plain programming?

Tags: ide, business-process-management

What do you prefer (from your developer's point of view) when it comes to implement a business process?

A Business Process Management System (BPMS) or just your favorite IDE with the needed tools and frameworks (a reporting tool for example)?

What is from your point of view the greatest Benefit of a BPMS compared to an IDE with your personal tools and frameworks?

OK. Maybe I should be more specific... I got to know one specific BPMS which should make it easy to implement a business process by configuring rules. But for me as a developer it is hard to work with the system. I would like to work with text files which I can refactor and I would like to be able to choose the right technology or framework for the job I have to do. Instead the system forces me to configure.

There are rules where I can use java, but even then I have to stick to the systems editor without intellisense etc.

So this leads me to the answer of my own question - I would like to use the tools I am used to instead of having to learn how to work with a BPMS (at least the one I know) because it limits me more than it helps. The BPMS I know is a framework from which it is hard to escape! At this time, I would prefer a framework like Grail over any BPMS I know.

So maybe the more specific question is: do you feel the same or are there BPMSes which support you in beeing a developer and think like a developer or do most of them force you to do your job a different way?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214122/is-bpm-in-your-mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you ask, but the choice BPM vs. plain programming will depend on the requirements. A "business process" is a relatively vague term in software engineering.

Here are a few criterion to evaluate your needs:

- *complexity of the rules* - Are the decisions/rules embodied in your process simple, complicated, configurable, hard-coded?
- *volatility of the process* - How frequently does your process change? Who should be able to make the change?
- *integration need* - Is your process realized using multiple heterogenous services, or is all implemented in the same language?
- *synchronous/asynchrounous* - Is your process "long-running" with the need to handle asynchronous actions?
- *human tasks* - Does your process involves human interaction, with task being assigned/routed to people according to their roles/responsibilities?
- *monitoring of the process* - What is the level of control you want on the existing process instances being executed? Do you need to audit the actions, etc. ?
- *error handling* - Depending on the previous points, how do you plan to deal with errors, or retry of faulty process execution?

Depending on the answer to these questions, you may realize that your process is closer to a [simple state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram) chart with a few actions and decisions that can be executed in a sequence, or you may realize that you need something more elaborated, and that you don't want to re-implement all that yourself.

Between **plain programming** and a **full-fledge BPM solution** (e.g. [Oracle BPM suite](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/bpm/index.htm) which contains [BPEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language), [rule engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine), etc.), there are **intermediate solutions** such as [jBPM](http://www.jboss.com/products/jbpm/) or [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) and probably a lot of others. These intermediate solution are frequently good trade-off.

Answer (score 13):

In my experience the development environments provided by BPMS systems are third rate, unproductive, and practically force you to write hard to maintain, poorly designed code (due to their limitations).  Almost all the "features" (UI, integrations, etc) provided by the BPMS system I'm familiar with (the one sold by that company named for its database) were not worth the money we paid.

If you're forced to use BPMS, as a developer, my advice would be to build as much of your application in a conventional development environment, such as Java or .Net, build as little as possible in the BPMS environment itself, and integrate the two.  The only things that should go in the BPMS is the minimum to make the business process work.

Comment: That's my experience, too. Only problem I see is that there is no clean interface between a workflow engine and the conventional development. And I guess there can't be, because both (the workflow and the application) try to drive the flow...

Answer (score 8):

I have worked with Biztalk in the past and more recently with JBPM. My opinion is biased against BPMs for the following reasons:

1. Steep learning curve : To make a process work, I have to understand how the system and the editor works. It is hard enough for a developer to understand  the system, let alone a business user. The drag and drop and visual representation is a great demo tool. It certainly impresses managers (who ultimately pay for it), but a developer's productivity just drops.
2. Non developers changing the workflow : I haven't seen one BPM solution do it flawlessly. Though it doesn't look like code, right click on the box and you do have to put some code, otherwise it is not going to work. So you definitely need a developer to do it. The best part is that it is neither developer friendly nor business user friendly, just demo user friendly.
3. Testablity and refactoring : It is virtually impossible to test drive a BPMS. You do have 'unit test frameworks' advertised, but most of them are hacks and hard to use. Recently I tried the JBPM one; I ended up writing a lot of glue code and fake workflow handlers to make it work. The deal breaker for me though is refactoring. If the business radically changes it's mind about how a business process should look, then good luck re-arranging the boxes, because just re-arranging them won't work, all the variables bound to the boxes also need to be re-arranged. I would prefer the power of the IDE and tests to refactor my business process.

If your application has workflow, then you could try a workflow library (with or without persistent state). It will still manage your workflows without all the bloat that comes with a BPM. If a business user needs to understand the code, then let the business prepare good process flowcharts and translate them into good domain driven code. Use cucumber style acceptance tests to make bring the developers and business together. A BPM is just something that tries to do too many things and ends up doing all those things badly.

Answer (score 5):

BPMS-- a lot of common business case, use case are already implemented. So you just have to know how to use it. For common workflow, you don't even need to write a single line of code, though mostly you would have to write some scripts to cover things that are not yet implemented.

Plain programming-- just use the IDE to hack out the code. The positive side: more control. The negative? A lot of times are spent on rewriting boilerplate code. And you have to maintain them.

So in a nutshell, I would prefer a Business Process Management System. One that I would recommend is [ProcessMaker](http://www.processmaker.com). It features an intuitive process designer that allows you to design workflow with drag and drop. And you can always write [trigger](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Triggers) to extend the process functionalities. It's open source as well.

Comment: So you get a better start with a BPMS since you already have your system in place and don't have to care about the login screen, session handling etc... But if you've to implement a lot of processes, is this still valid? I mean with the first process, you've implemented your boilerplate code which you can reuse for the second...

Comment: Yes, with BPMS it's still faster to go